# Google Cache Handling For Multi City Page

Tags: google, cache

Recently i have been checking Google cache for the page `https://in.example.com/hyderabad/events/speed-date-singles-with-lol/ET00054188` where i am getting cache of this url -  `https://in.example.com/mumbai/events/speed-date-singles-with-lol/ET00054188`. This case is happening on checking out for every city page of this event. Even these pages have self canonical pointing to the same city.

Comment: Do these pages have a canonical tag pointing to the same page? If so then what Google is doing makes sense. If not, your question is not clear.

Comment: Yes their canonical are pointing to the same url. Its just that for a particular region we want particular city url to rank.